# Curly brackets in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found the following line in a tutorial on jQuery:

```
$tbody.append(`<tr>${abc+ def}</tr>`);
```

What does the curly brackets do in that case?
So, what's the purpose of this part:

```
${abc + def}
```

Comment: it's nothing to do with jQuery - it's javascript ... [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: jQuery is an ECMAScript library, not a completely different programming language. ECMAScript doesn't allow changing the syntax, so this syntax *cannot possibly* have anything to do with jQuery.

Comment: Read about [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature is not related to `jQuery` and is called **[template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).** It is a new feature, appeared in **ES6**. It will evaluate the `${abc + def}` and put the value in the string.

This in **ES6**

```
`<tr>${abc+ def}</tr>`
```

is equivalent to this in **ES5**

```
"<tr>" + (abc + def) + "</tr>"
```

Comment: you may want to add that this has nothing at all to do with jQuery

Comment: You should mention that the first example is ECMA v6 and the latter ECMA v5

Comment: @Legends Edited